# How do I put collapsible menus inside of other collapsible menus?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to make my first addon today for Blender 2.8. I have a problem with the way the engines are currently set up because you need to leave Cycles Render to get to the EEVEE settings and leave EEVEE to get to the Cycles settings. This addon is meant to put EEVEE property panel options like bloom and SSR into the Cycles properties panel. This works perfectly but it looks messy. The options are all in the same section as the Cycles options:
[image]

I would like to make a collapsible menu inside of the Cycles properties panel called "Real-time Options" and under that, I'd like to put the EEVEE options. So how do I make a collapsible menu with other collapsible menus inside of it?

**Edit:**
Something like this would be nice:
[image: Changing option in box changes available options]

This would be good. You see how when I switch from path tracing to branched path tracing it gives me different options? This would be perfect.

My addon code:

```
    bl_info = {"name": "Unifier", "category": "Object"}

import bpy
from bpy_extras.node_utils import find_node_input, find_output_node

from bpy.types import (
        Panel,
        Menu,
        Operator,
        )

class CYCLES_MT_sampling_presets(Menu):
    bl_label = "Sampling Presets"
    preset_subdir = "cycles/sampling"
    preset_operator = "script.execute_preset"
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'CYCLES'}
    draw = Menu.draw_preset


class CYCLES_MT_integrator_presets(Menu):
    bl_label = "Integrator Presets"
    preset_subdir = "cycles/integrator"
    preset_operator = "script.execute_preset"
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'CYCLES'}
    draw = Menu.draw_preset


class CyclesButtonsPanel:
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "render"
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES


def get_device_type(context):
    return context.user_preferences.addons[__package__].preferences.compute_device_type


def use_cpu(context):
    cscene = context.scene.cycles

    return (get_device_type(context) == 'NONE' or cscene.device == 'CPU')


def use_opencl(context):
    cscene = context.scene.cycles

    return (get_device_type(context) == 'OPENCL' and cscene.device == 'GPU')


def use_cuda(context):
    cscene = context.scene.cycles

    return (get_device_type(context) == 'CUDA' and cscene.device == 'GPU')


def use_branched_path(context):
    cscene = context.scene.cycles

    return (cscene.progressive == 'BRANCHED_PATH')


def use_sample_all_lights(context):
    cscene = context.scene.cycles

    return cscene.sample_all_lights_direct or cscene.sample_all_lights_indirect

def show_device_active(context):
    cscene = context.scene.cycles
    if cscene.device != 'GPU':
        return True
    return context.user_preferences.addons[__package__].preferences.has_active_device()


def draw_samples_info(layout, context):
    cscene = context.scene.cycles
    integrator = cscene.progressive

    # Calculate sample values
    if integrator == 'PATH':
        aa = cscene.samples
        if cscene.use_square_samples:
            aa = aa * aa
    else:
        aa = cscene.aa_samples
        d = cscene.diffuse_samples
        g = cscene.glossy_samples
        t = cscene.transmission_samples
        ao = cscene.ao_samples
        ml = cscene.mesh_light_samples
        sss = cscene.subsurface_samples
        vol = cscene.volume_samples

        if cscene.use_square_samples:
            aa = aa * aa
            d = d * d
            g = g * g
            t = t * t
            ao = ao * ao
            ml = ml * ml
            sss = sss * sss
            vol = vol * vol

    # Draw interface
    # Do not draw for progressive, when Square Samples are disabled
    if use_branched_path(context) or (cscene.use_square_samples and integrator == 'PATH'):
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.scale_y = 0.6
        col.label("Total Samples:")
        col.separator()
        if integrator == 'PATH':
            col.label("%s AA" % aa)
        else:
            col.label("%s AA, %s Diffuse, %s Glossy, %s Transmission" %
                      (aa, d * aa, g * aa, t * aa))
            col.separator()
            col.label("%s AO, %s Mesh Light, %s Subsurface, %s Volume" %
                      (ao * aa, ml * aa, sss * aa, vol * aa))


#EEVEE settings
class RENDER_PT_eevee_ambient_occlusion(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Ambient Occlusion"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES)

    def draw_header(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee
        self.layout.prop(props, "gtao_enable", text="")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee

        layout.active = props.gtao_enable
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(props, "gtao_use_bent_normals")
        col.prop(props, "gtao_bounce")
        col.prop(props, "gtao_distance")
        col.prop(props, "gtao_factor")
        col.prop(props, "gtao_quality")


class RENDER_PT_eevee_motion_blur(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Motion Blur"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES)

    def draw_header(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee
        self.layout.prop(props, "motion_blur_enable", text="")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee

        layout.active = props.motion_blur_enable
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(props, "motion_blur_samples")
        col.prop(props, "motion_blur_shutter")


class RENDER_PT_eevee_depth_of_field(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Depth of Field"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES)

    def draw_header(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee
        self.layout.prop(props, "dof_enable", text="")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee

        layout.active = props.dof_enable
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(props, "bokeh_max_size")
        col.prop(props, "bokeh_threshold")


class RENDER_PT_eevee_bloom(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Bloom"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES)

    def draw_header(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee
        self.layout.prop(props, "bloom_enable", text="")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee

        layout.active = props.bloom_enable
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(props, "bloom_threshold")
        col.prop(props, "bloom_knee")
        col.prop(props, "bloom_radius")
        col.prop(props, "bloom_color")
        col.prop(props, "bloom_intensity")
        col.prop(props, "bloom_clamp")


class RENDER_PT_eevee_volumetric(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Volumetric"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES)

    def draw_header(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee
        self.layout.prop(props, "volumetric_enable", text="")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee

        layout.active = props.volumetric_enable
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(props, "volumetric_start")
        col.prop(props, "volumetric_end")
        col.prop(props, "volumetric_tile_size")
        col.prop(props, "volumetric_samples")
        col.prop(props, "volumetric_sample_distribution")
        col.prop(props, "volumetric_lights")
        col.prop(props, "volumetric_light_clamp")
        col.prop(props, "volumetric_shadows")
        col.prop(props, "volumetric_shadow_samples")
        col.prop(props, "volumetric_colored_transmittance")


class RENDER_PT_eevee_subsurface_scattering(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Subsurface Scattering"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES)

    def draw_header(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee
        self.layout.prop(props, "sss_enable", text="")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee

        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(props, "sss_samples")
        col.prop(props, "sss_jitter_threshold")
        col.prop(props, "sss_separate_albedo")


class RENDER_PT_eevee_screen_space_reflections(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Screen Space Reflections"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES)

    def draw_header(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee
        self.layout.prop(props, "ssr_enable", text="")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee

        col = layout.column()
        col.active = props.ssr_enable
        col.prop(props, "ssr_refraction")
        col.prop(props, "ssr_halfres")
        col.prop(props, "ssr_quality")
        col.prop(props, "ssr_max_roughness")
        col.prop(props, "ssr_thickness")
        col.prop(props, "ssr_border_fade")
        col.prop(props, "ssr_firefly_fac")


class RENDER_PT_eevee_shadows(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Shadows"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee

        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(props, "shadow_method")
        col.prop(props, "shadow_cube_size")
        col.prop(props, "shadow_cascade_size")
        col.prop(props, "shadow_high_bitdepth")


class RENDER_PT_eevee_sampling(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Sampling"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee

        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(props, "taa_samples")
        col.prop(props, "taa_render_samples")
        col.prop(props, "taa_reprojection")


class RENDER_PT_eevee_indirect_lighting(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Indirect Lighting"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.eevee

        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(props, "gi_diffuse_bounces")
        col.prop(props, "gi_cubemap_resolution")
        col.prop(props, "gi_visibility_resolution")


class RENDER_PT_eevee_film(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Film"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.engine in cls.COMPAT_ENGINES)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        rd = scene.render

        split = layout.split()

        col = split.column()
        col.prop(rd, "filter_size")

        col = split.column()
        col.prop(rd, "alpha_mode", text="Alpha")

def draw_device(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    layout = self.layout

    if context.engine == 'CYCLES':
        from . import engine
        cscene = scene.cycles

        split = layout.split(percentage=1 / 3)
        split.label("Feature Set:")
        split.prop(cscene, "feature_set", text="")

        split = layout.split(percentage=1 / 3)
        split.label("Device:")
        row = split.row()
        row.active = show_device_active(context)
        row.prop(cscene, "device", text="")

        if engine.with_osl() and use_cpu(context):
            layout.prop(cscene, "shading_system")


def draw_pause(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    scene = context.scene

    if context.engine == "CYCLES":
        view = context.space_data

        cscene = scene.cycles
        layout.prop(cscene, "preview_pause", icon="PAUSE", text="")


def get_panels():
    exclude_panels = {
        'DATA_PT_area',
        'DATA_PT_camera_dof',
        'DATA_PT_falloff_curve',
        'DATA_PT_lamp',
        'DATA_PT_preview',
        'DATA_PT_spot',
        'MATERIAL_PT_context_material',
        'MATERIAL_PT_preview',
        'VIEWLAYER_PT_filter',
        'VIEWLAYER_PT_layer_passes',
        'RENDER_PT_post_processing',
        'SCENE_PT_simplify',
        }

    panels = []
    for panel in bpy.types.Panel.__subclasses__():
        if hasattr(panel, 'COMPAT_ENGINES') and 'BLENDER_RENDER' in panel.COMPAT_ENGINES:
            if panel.__name__ not in exclude_panels:
                panels.append(panel)

    return panels


classes = (
    CYCLES_MT_sampling_presets,
    CYCLES_MT_integrator_presets,
    RENDER_PT_eevee_ambient_occlusion,
    RENDER_PT_eevee_motion_blur,
    RENDER_PT_eevee_depth_of_field,
    RENDER_PT_eevee_bloom,
    RENDER_PT_eevee_volumetric,
    RENDER_PT_eevee_subsurface_scattering,
    RENDER_PT_eevee_screen_space_reflections,
    RENDER_PT_eevee_shadows,
    RENDER_PT_eevee_sampling,
    RENDER_PT_eevee_indirect_lighting,
    RENDER_PT_eevee_film,
)


def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class

    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.append(draw_device)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.append(draw_pause)

    for panel in get_panels():
        panel.COMPAT_ENGINES.add('CYCLES')

    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class

    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.remove(draw_device)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.remove(draw_pause)

    for panel in get_panels():
        if 'CYCLES' in panel.COMPAT_ENGINES:
            panel.COMPAT_ENGINES.remove('CYCLES')

    for cls in classes:
        unregister_class(cls)
```

Comment: Do you want something that expands like the outliner? Are there any examples in the UI similar.? eg addon prefs  - keysets?

Comment: I suggest creating a simpler portion of code that still demonstrates what you need (but actually is any of your code related to the question?). As batFINGER said, best to find somewhere in the UI or an add-on that has this functionality so we can see what you mean.

Comment: @RayMairlot I tried to give an example in my edit.